# Smaller Cloud Carousel

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new with jquery and i am trying to rescale the cloud carousel to be a bit less high. However, somehow I can't seem to find any height indicator in the whole code.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CloudCarousel V1.0.5
// (c) 2011 by R Cecco. <http://www.professorcloud.com>
// MIT License
//
// Reflection code based on plugin by Christophe Beyls <http://www.digitalia.be>
//
// Please retain this copyright header in all versions of the software
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

(function($) {

    // START Reflection object.
    // Creates a reflection for underneath an image.
    // IE uses an image with IE specific filter properties, other browsers use the Canvas tag.  
    // The position and size of the reflection gets updated by updateAll() in Controller.
    function Reflection(img, reflHeight, opacity) {             

        var reflection, cntx, imageWidth = img.width, imageHeight = img.width, gradient, parent;

        parent = $(img.parentNode);
        this.element = reflection = parent.append("<canvas class='reflection' style='position:absolute'/>").find(':last')[0];
        if ( !reflection.getContext &&  $.browser.msie) {
            this.element = reflection = parent.append("<img class='reflection' style='position:absolute'/>").find(':last')[0];                  
            reflection.src = img.src;           
            reflection.style.filter = "flipv progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=" + (opacity * 100) + ", style=1, finishOpacity=0, startx=0, starty=0, finishx=0, finishy=" + (reflHeight / imageHeight * 100) + ")";  

        } else {                            
            cntx = reflection.getContext("2d");
            try {


                $(reflection).attr({width: imageWidth, height: reflHeight});
                cntx.save();
                cntx.translate(0, imageHeight-1);
                cntx.scale(1, -1);              
                cntx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);             
                cntx.restore();
                cntx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
                gradient = cntx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, reflHeight);
                gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, " + (1 - opacity) + ")");
                gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");
                cntx.fillStyle = gradient;
                cntx.fillRect(0, 0, imageWidth, reflHeight);                
            } catch(e) {            
                return;
            }       
        }
        // Store a copy of the alt and title attrs into the reflection
        $(reflection).attr({ 'alt': $(img).attr('alt'), title: $(img).attr('title')} ); 

    }   //END Reflection object

    // START Item object.
    // A wrapper object for items within the carousel.
    var Item = function(imgIn, options)
    {                               
        this.orgWidth = imgIn.width;            
        this.orgHeight = imgIn.height;      
        this.image = imgIn;
        this.reflection = null;                 
        this.alt = imgIn.alt;
        this.title = imgIn.title;
        this.imageOK = false;       
        this.options = options;             

        this.imageOK = true;    

        if (this.options.reflHeight > 0)
        {                                                   
            this.reflection = new Reflection(this.image, this.options.reflHeight, this.options.reflOpacity);                    
        }
        $(this.image).css('position','absolute');   // Bizarre. This seems to reset image width to 0 on webkit!                 
    };// END Item object


    // Controller object.
    // This handles moving all the items, dealing with mouse clicks etc.    
    var Controller = function(container, images, options)
    {                       
        var items = [], funcSin = Math.sin, funcCos = Math.cos, ctx=this;
        this.controlTimer = 0;
        this.stopped = false;
        //this.imagesLoaded = 0;
        this.container = container;
        this.xRadius = options.xRadius;
        this.yRadius = options.yRadius;
        this.showFrontTextTimer = 0;
        this.autoRotateTimer = 0;
        if (options.xRadius === 0)
        {
            this.xRadius = ($(container).width()/2.3);
        }
        if (options.yRadius === 0)
        {
            this.yRadius = ($(container).height()/6);
        }

        this.xCentre = options.xPos;
        this.yCentre = options.yPos;
        this.frontIndex = 0;    // Index of the item at the front

        // Start with the first item at the front.
        this.rotation = this.destRotation = Math.PI/2;
        this.timeDelay = 1000/options.FPS;

        // Turn on the infoBox
        if(options.altBox !== null)
        {
            $(options.altBox).css('display','block');   
            $(options.titleBox).css('display','block'); 
        }
        // Turn on relative position for container to allow absolutely positioned elements
        // within it to work.
        $(container).css({ position:'relative', overflow:'hidden'} );

        $(options.buttonLeft).css('display','inline');
        $(options.buttonRight).css('display','inline');

        // Setup the buttons.
        $(options.buttonLeft).bind('mouseup',this,function(event){
            event.data.rotate(-1);  
            return false;
        });
        $(options.buttonRight).bind('mouseup',this,function(event){                                                         
            event.data.rotate(1);   
            return false;
        });

        // You will need this plugin for the mousewheel to work: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel
        if (options.mouseWheel)
        {
            $(container).bind('mousewheel',this,function(event, delta) {                     
                     event.data.rotate(delta);
                     return false;
                 });
        }
        $(container).bind('mouseover click',this,function(event){

            clearInterval(event.data.autoRotateTimer);      // Stop auto rotation if mouse over.
            var text = $(event.target).attr('alt');     
            // If we have moved over a carousel item, then show the alt and title text.

            if ( text !== undefined && text !== null )
            {

                clearTimeout(event.data.showFrontTextTimer);            
                $(options.altBox).html( ($(event.target).attr('alt') ));
                $(options.titleBox).html( ($(event.target).attr('title') ));                            
                if ( options.bringToFront && event.type == 'click' )                
                {

                    var idx = $(event.target).data('itemIndex');    
                    var frontIndex = event.data.frontIndex;
                    //var   diff = idx - frontIndex;                    
                    var        diff = (idx - frontIndex) % images.length;
                    if (Math.abs(diff) > images.length / 2) {
                        diff += (diff > 0 ? -images.length : images.length);
                    }

                    event.data.rotate(-diff);
                }
            }
        });
        // If we have moved out of a carousel item (or the container itself),
        // restore the text of the front item in 1 second.
        $(container).bind('mouseout',this,function(event){
                var context = event.data;               
                clearTimeout(context.showFrontTextTimer);               
                context.showFrontTextTimer = setTimeout( function(){context.showFrontText();},1000);
                context.autoRotate();   // Start auto rotation.
        });

        // Prevent items from being selected as mouse is moved and clicked in the container.
        $(container).bind('mousedown',this,function(event){ 

            event.data.container.focus();
            return false;
        });
        container.onselectstart = function () { return false; };        // For IE.

        this.innerWrapper = $(container).wrapInner('<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;"/>').children()[0];

        // Shows the text from the front most item.
        this.showFrontText = function()
        {   
            if ( items[this.frontIndex] === undefined ) { return; } // Images might not have loaded yet.
            $(options.titleBox).html( $(items[this.frontIndex].image).attr('title'));
            $(options.altBox).html( $(items[this.frontIndex].image).attr('alt'));               
        };

        this.go = function()
        {               
            if(this.controlTimer !== 0) { return; }
            var context = this;
            this.controlTimer = setTimeout( function(){context.updateAll();},this.timeDelay);                   
        };

        this.stop = function()
        {
            clearTimeout(this.controlTimer);
            this.controlTimer = 0;              
        };


        // Starts the rotation of the carousel. Direction is the number (+-) of carousel items to rotate by.
        this.rotate = function(direction)
        {   
            this.frontIndex -= direction;
            this.frontIndex %= items.length;                                
            this.destRotation += ( Math.PI / items.length ) * ( 2*direction );
            this.showFrontText();
            this.go();          
        };


        this.autoRotate = function()
        {           
            if ( options.autoRotate !== 'no' )
            {
                var dir = (options.autoRotate === 'right')? 1 : -1;
                this.autoRotateTimer = setInterval( function(){ctx.rotate(dir); }, options.autoRotateDelay );
            }
        };

        // This is the main loop function that moves everything.
        this.updateAll = function()
        {                                           
            var minScale = options.minScale;    // This is the smallest scale applied to the furthest item.
            var smallRange = (1-minScale) * 0.5;
            var w,h,x,y,scale,item,sinVal;

            var change = (this.destRotation - this.rotation);               
            var absChange = Math.abs(change);

            this.rotation += change * options.speed;
            if ( absChange < 0.001 ) { this.rotation = this.destRotation; }         
            var itemsLen = items.length;
            var spacing = (Math.PI / itemsLen) * 2; 
            //var   wrapStyle = null;
            var radians = this.rotation;
            var isMSIE = $.browser.msie;

            // Turn off display. This can reduce repaints/reflows when making style and position changes in the loop.
            // See http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=3          
            this.innerWrapper.style.display = 'none';       

            var style;
            var px = 'px', reflHeight;  
            var context = this;
            for (var i = 0; i<itemsLen ;i++)
            {
                item = items[i];

                sinVal = funcSin(radians);

                scale = ((sinVal+1) * smallRange) + minScale;

                x = this.xCentre + (( (funcCos(radians) * this.xRadius) - (item.orgWidth*0.5)) * scale);
                y = this.yCentre + (( (sinVal * this.yRadius)  ) * scale);      

                if (item.imageOK)
                {
                    var img = item.image;
                    w = img.width = item.orgWidth * scale;                  
                    h = img.height = item.orgHeight * scale;
                    img.style.left = x + px ;
                    img.style.top = y + px;
                    img.style.zIndex = "" + (scale * 100)>>0;   // >>0 = Math.foor(). Firefox doesn't like fractional decimals in z-index.
                    if (item.reflection !== null)
                    {                                                                                                       
                        reflHeight = options.reflHeight * scale;                        
                        style = item.reflection.element.style;
                        style.left = x + px;
                        style.top = y + h + options.reflGap * scale + px;
                        style.width = w + px;                               
                        if (isMSIE)
                        {                                           
                            style.filter.finishy = (reflHeight / h * 100);              
                        }else
                        {                               
                            style.height = reflHeight + px;                                                         
                        }                                                                                                                   
                    }                   
                }
                radians += spacing;
            }
            // Turn display back on.                    
            this.innerWrapper.style.display = 'block';

            // If we have a preceptable change in rotation then loop again next frame.
            if ( absChange >= 0.001 )
            {               
                this.controlTimer = setTimeout( function(){context.updateAll();},this.timeDelay);       
            }else
            {
                // Otherwise just stop completely.              
                this.stop();
            }
        }; // END updateAll     

        // Create an Item object for each image 
//      func = function(){return;ctx.updateAll();} ;

        // Check if images have loaded. We need valid widths and heights for the reflections.
        this.checkImagesLoaded = function()
        {
            var i;
            for(i=0;i<images.length;i++) {
                if ( (images[i].width === undefined) || ( (images[i].complete !== undefined) && (!images[i].complete)  ))
                {
                    return;                 
                }               
            }
            for(i=0;i<images.length;i++) {              
                 items.push( new Item( images[i], options ) );  
                 $(images[i]).data('itemIndex',i);
            }
            // If all images have valid widths and heights, we can stop checking.           
            clearInterval(this.tt);
            this.showFrontText();
            this.autoRotate();  
            this.updateAll();

        };

        this.tt = setInterval( function(){ctx.checkImagesLoaded();},50);    
    }; // END Controller object

    // The jQuery plugin part. Iterates through items specified in selector and inits a Controller class for each one.
    $.fn.CloudCarousel = function(options) {

        this.each( function() {         

            options = $.extend({}, {
                               reflHeight:0,
                               reflOpacity:0.5,
                               reflGap:0,
                               minScale:0.5,
                               xPos:0,
                               yPos:0,
                               xRadius:0,
                               yRadius:0,
                               altBox:null,
                               titleBox:null,
                               FPS: 30,
                               autoRotate: 'no',
                               autoRotateDelay: 1500,
                               speed:0.2,
                               mouseWheel: false,
                                 bringToFront: false
            },options );                                    
            // Create a Controller for each carousel.       
            $(this).data('cloudcarousel', new Controller( this, $('.cloudcarousel',$(this)), options) );
        });             
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

THis here initiates the script, but also no height options

```
$("#carousel1").CloudCarousel(      
    {           
        reflHeight: 40,
        reflGap:2,
        titleBox: $('#da-vinci-title'),
        altBox: $('#da-vinci-alt'),
        buttonLeft: $('#slider-left-but'),
        buttonRight: $('#slider-right-but'),
        yRadius:30,
        xPos: 480,
        yPos: 32,
        speed:0.15,
    }
);
```

Comment: Maybe the `yRadius` less?

Comment: Sadly tha only edits the tilt of the carousel (so higher numbers make it more perpendicular and lower ones more flat, but the space remains there)

Comment: This is a guess but have you tried adding `minScale:0.3,` (or perhaps minScale:0.8, -- not sure which way it should go).

Comment: That changes the scale of the furthest one :P So 0.1 gives you a tiny back pic while the first is the same size.

Comment: It would be better for us to have some test page. The code as is is showing a blank page and there are no errors at all in the code for any checks to make.

Comment: Doesn't the carousel come with a css file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end result you're after ("trying to rescale the cloud carousel to be a bit less high") is a little vague but based on your responses to the comments, it reads as if you want to decrease the radius of the carousel circle. After you change that, everything else can be manipulated via the current options.

It appears line 230 of cloud-carousel.1.0.5.js determines the size of the radius.

```
var smallRange = (1-minScale) * 0.5;
```

Replacing the .5 value produces the following results.

**.75** 
[image: .75 Value]

**.5** 
[image: .5 Value]

**.25** 
[image: .25 Value]

**.15** 
[image: .15 Value]

Unfortunately, you will need to edit the source to change this value. You could hard code the value you need in or update the options to include this value. This requires a minor change to the CloudCarousel source. The code changes and a working example included below.

#### Line 230

```
var smallRange = (1-minScale) * options.carouselRadius;
```

#### Line 352

```
carouselRadius: .5,
```

#### Working Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8V8JZ/

Comment: Decreasing `yPos` will move the content inside the black box up. Updating the `height` in the `div` will make the black box smaller. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8V8JZ/1/ Is this what you're after?

Comment: If you want to use the option I added, you will need to link to or keep a [copy of the edited code](http://johnsuarez.com/stackoverflow/jsuar.cloud-carousel.1.0.5.js). I don't recommend linking to the code on my website as it may not always be there.

Comment: Ok got it to work! Used your js code from the fiddle and my code call in the header. `$(document).ready(function(){
         
 // This initialises carousels on the container elements specified, in this case, carousel1.
 $("#carousel1").CloudCarousel(  
  {   
   reflHeight: 40,
   reflGap:2,
   titleBox: $('#da-vinci-title'),
   altBox: $('#da-vinci-alt'),
   buttonLeft: $('#slider-left-but'),
   buttonRight: $('#slider-right-but'),
   yRadius:30,
   xPos: 480,
   yPos: 32,
   speed:0.15,
   carouselRadius: .3,
  }
 );
});`

Comment: Damn that pasted code looks ugly xD 
Also, the line number in your post (252) should be 352. I'd edit it but it doesn't let me.

Comment: Thanks I updated it. I recommend pulling my code down and keeping a copy on your server. That link will probably not work at some point.

Comment: I saved it on my server, so it's fine. Thanks again! 
JQuery really is different from the other languages I know, so still got a lot to learn. :P

Comment: As programmers we are always learning. Glad I could. Don't forget to apply the bounty :)

Comment: I'm new at bounties xD Though that by approving you'd get it. :P 
Anyways, it should work now, enjoy!